# unzip: invalid Zip Magic 0A0A0A0A

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am creating a Docker image
in the dockerfile adding the ZIPped file of an agent from github using curl

it downloads successfully , but when i run unzip i get this error

> ---> Running in 4fa3caf0a552   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average
>   Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100 28576    0 28576    0     0  38720      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>   --:--:-- 38668 Archive:  java-agent.zip  unzip: invalid zip magic 0A0A0A0A

Comment: https://github.com/wahern/luaossl/issues/103

Comment: Resolved it, the issue was with the ZIP file. Zipped it again and works fine